# pandas exlewriter.book does not read my excel file and even break the existed file

Tags: pandas, openpyxl, pandas.excelwriter

I want to stack a series of dataframe in one excel file and I wrote the code below.

```
if os.path.isfile(result) is False:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(result, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        raw_data.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet1, index=False)      
else:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(result, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        writer.book=openpyxl.load_workbook(result)
        raw_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet2, index=False)
```

The initial creation of the excel file works fine, but after the file had been created, the error occurred at the step `writer.book=openpyxl.load_workbook(result)` like below.

```
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible
```

And, after this error, the size of existed file had changed and file did not open.

Before:

[image: xlsx file before]

After:

[image: xlsx file after]

Is there any idea to solve this problem?

---

There are some ambiguities in my previous code, and the code below might be much clear

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import openpyxl as oxl

resultpath=r'D:/CODE/result.xlsx'

for i in range(5):
    sheet = 'Sheet'+ str(i)
    result = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10), 'b': range(10)})
    if os.path.isfile(resultpath) is False:
        with pd.ExcelWriter(resultpath, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
            result.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet, index=False)
             
    else:
        with pd.ExcelWriter(resultpath, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
            writer.book =oxl.load_workbook(resultpath)
            result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False)
```

the version of each package is presented below.

Pandas : 1.4.2
openpyxl : 3.0.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem

Using the 'mode' property of ExcelWriter solves this problem and also makes code easy to read.

The modified code is below and it works fine

```
import pandas as pd
import os

result = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10), 'b': range(10)})

resultpath=r'D:/CODE/test.xlsx'

for i in range(5):
    sheet = 'Sheet'+ str(i)
    if not os.path.exists(resultpath):   
        with pd.ExcelWriter(resultpath, mode='w', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
            result.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=sheet)
    else:   
        with pd.ExcelWriter(resultpath, mode='a', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
            result.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=sheet)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welecome to Stackoverflow.
The `sheet_name` should be in quotes. Also, always good practice to save the file `writer.save()` after writing. The updated code would work fine...

```
if os.path.isfile(result) is False:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(result, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        raw_data.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
        writer.save()
else:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(result, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        writer.book=openpyxl.load_workbook(result)
        raw_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2', index=False)
        writer.save()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work and the same errors occured...

Comment: Did you delete the bad results.xlsx file already present? Do that first and then start....